# Two developer GIT workflow and setup with automatic deployment

Tags: git

We're two developers working on a website. I've been through the progit book but I'm battling to understand what would be the correct workflow and setup for us. We would like the production and staging servers to be automatically updated when we do the relevant commits. Any advice on how we could optimize this workflow or if we are doing anything wrong would be greatly appreciated. My current thoughts are below:

### Local workstations

**local repo branches**

- master (development) tracking origin/master
- production tracking origin/production

**Workflow**

1. General development is done by branching off master and merging
   changes back in.
2. When ready to share updates with partner and test
       on live web server, push master to origin.
3. When testing is complete
           on web server, merge master into production and push production to
           origin.

### Web server (origin)

- Bare repo with master and production branches.
- 2 virtual servers, one for staging other for production.
- The doc root for each virtual    server is a git repo which pulls
  from the bare repo on the same    server.
- The bare repo has a post commit hook that detects which    branch has
  been commited to. If the master branch is commited, a git    pull
  origin/master is done from the staging virtual server doc root.    If
  production branch is commited, a git pull origin/production is
  done from the production virtual server doc root.

Comment: Just a side note: The number of times I see people put a word in parentheses after the word "master" is very very high. "Master" is the default name for the first branch, but you're not stuck with it. I pretty much always rename it to something meaningful. Most of my actual working repos don't HAVE a branch named "master". If it's development, name it "development".

Comment: @DanRay - Great point, I didn't realize master could be renamed. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

In accordance with [a successful git branching model by nvie.com](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/), we branch off `devel` and have `master` as production branch.

Additionally, we hooked into `post-update` to trigger deploy and building of docs, which then happens deferredly (publish/subscribe via XMPP).

Otherwise it's really the same and looks pretty sensible to me.